# Excel single cell editing

Tags: microsoft-excel

When using Microsoft Excel it frequently happens that when I click on a cell with the intention of editing it multiple cells below that cell are highlighted. If I ignore the fact that multiple cells have been highlighted and edit the data I get the result I want, but if I wish to copy and paste, all the cells highlighted are copied and pasted! Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: I can only provide an educated guess that it could be that your mouse settings are too sensitive or the mouse should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy only one cell, select only one cell before you issue the copy command.

Data entry and copying cells are two different things.

Data entry with several cells selected will submit the data to the currently active cell when you hit the Enter key. If you use Ctrl-Enter, the edits will be applied to all cells in the selection.

The Copy command, however, will always be applied to all selected cells and there is no way of turning that off.

Comment: What happens is n ot the issue.

Comment: I intended to add to the previous 'comment' that the issue is why is more than one cell being highlighted when I click on only the one cell.

Comment: You'd have to edit your post and show an example where it happens. Post a link to a workbook. Point to the cell that causes more than one cell to be selected when you click it. This is not normal behaviour, but what's causing it would need inspection of the workbook, not speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only experience this problem when using Page Layout view?

There is a known bug that affected Excel at least through the 2010 version in Page Layout view:  I do not remember the detail precisely enough, sadly, even I experienced it myself only a year ago, but it involved something about headers and footers while in Page Layout view (even without them beeing used, they "show" as in "Click to add header"). It seems to me it revolved around having a full page showing PLUS the header of the page shown below it. We solved it by making sure the zoom level was high enough to push the page below its header past the Tabs so it did not show.

Getting the exact Zoom needed for that when one wants precisely one page to show is tedious, but... there it is. Myself, not an issue as I only us Page Layout view to get measurements in inches, not points. The co-worker who encountered it first though, he needs full pages showing.

(By the way, by "this" I specifically mean that one finds selecting a cell with the mouse behaves as if one is holding the Control key at the same time. So say A1 is currently selected and one clicks F9, one sees that block highlighted. However, one can use the arrow keys to move "safely" AND one also experiences selecting a cell, A1 for instance, and (usually) exactly three cells below it are also highlighted as if one had Shift-Clicked.)

You will see many attempts at using Zoom in a blunt fashion, i.e.:  'Zoom up 10-20-30% then back down some, that solves it for me' but those folk are just ending, by chance, at a place where the page below's header does not show. EXT is bruted about too, but the same dynamic is at work. "Sticky Keys" and bad mice, clumsy mouse handling:  these only seem possible when one is not noticing that it only happens in Page Layout view so it seems it goes away when, say, using a different mouse.

Also, the portion of the top of the page below that is NOT a header CAN show, just not any part of the header region itself. This leads to another thought which I will present to my co-worker:  If one goes into the print options and sets the header height to zero (0), perhaps any old amount of the next page can show without trouble. Not perfect, one may want to have a header, but... And of course, one might finish the layout work, THEN add the headers.